# Verbose output in jest js

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, jestjs

is any option for verbore output for testing by jest?

I can see which modules are mocked.

I tried

```
jasmine.VERBOSE = true;
```

but not working.

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 51):

To get verbose mode in Jest, you can run Jest with the `--verbose` tag.

In your `packages.json`, you can write:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest --verbose"
 },
```

Then you can run `npm test`

Alternatively, if you are using `gulp-jest`, to get Jest in verbose mode, find the `index.js` file of the `gulp-jest` folder in `node_modules` and add a verbose: true to the `jest.runCLI` block.

```
jest.runCLI({
  config: options,
  verbose: true
}
```

Answer (score 11):

simple add in package.json

```
{
...
...

 "jest": {
         "verbose": true
 },
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create jest.config.js file in root directory and add this to the module export

```
module.exports = {
    // some code here..
    verbose: true,
    // some code here...
}
```